# Questions on health business

Tags: discussion

I am currently doing some research on business and procedures in the healthcare industry.

For example, the role of different actors, how does money move, bundle payments, outcome-based contracts, etc.

I'm looking for the right place to ask those question. Is this exchange OK? Or can someone suggest a better one?

Comment: I can’t suggest a better one, but I doubt you would get very good answers here. You can always give it a try ;). I’ll take the blaming for any outrages... [chat] might also be a good place although we have little to none activity there...

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Please explain.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt [voting on meta is different](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) and up votes can mean that is a good question or *yes* and down votes can mean that is a bad question or *no*. While the yes/no part is supposed to be reserved for [tag:feature-request] it often carries over to other question. My guess is the down vote means that questions on health business are not on topic.

Comment: @StrongBad the question does not take any stance on whether business questions should be on topic. Downvotes are therefore hard to interpret.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the question is *Is this exchange OK?* to which I interpret the down vote to mean *no*

Comment: @StrongBad I read "I'm looking for the right place to ask those question. Is this exchange OK? Or can someone suggest a better one?"

Comment: I have similar interests. I work in healthcare IT and a venue to ask professionals in the community at large. My questions about actors would be similar to @Nathan-H and would also include things about what health professionals see or do rather than about specific medical questions.

Answer (score 3):

These questions would be clearly out of scope according to our [on-topic page](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), that said, I would really like to see our scope be expanded to include things like the health care industry. As we are a beta site, our scope is still developing so I think you should ask away.

Comment: I think that an SE for questions about the healthcare industry would be extremely valuable to a lot of people. If it were a separate SE than this one, that would work, but I would be concerned about overlap. The fact that SuperUser is a topical superset of AskUbuntu, for example, is burdensome to moderators and users.

Comment: I am reading the on-topic page. Is it fair to consider Health.SE in the same vein as WebMD?